# Redirecting a number of buttons to a single form in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have like 40 pieces of buttons in a single form and I want them to display another form when clicked. Is there a way of doing this or I just have to manually code them one by one by?

```
private void btnRect0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        viewSchedule form = new viewSchedule();
        form.Show();
    }
```

I would have to type this for 40 times and I want to avoid that.

Comment: Just link all buttons to the same click event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Mattias suggested, you can create one event, then in the properties window of your buttons, you can link the `Click` event to the already created event (I'm using 2010, but 2012 should be similar):

[image]

Comment: I didn't quite get @Mattias's comment at first but you were able to clear things out. Made my life a lot easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write separate handlers doing the same thing, you can add one handler to all buttons' events, like so:

```
btnRect0.Clicked+=new System.EventHandler(btnRect0_Click);
btnRect1.Clicked+=new System.EventHandler(btnRect0_Click);
btnRect2.Clicked+=new System.EventHandler(btnRect0_Click);
...
```

If you're using the Designer, select all the buttons, and click on the lightning bolt in the `Properties` window. This will bring up the Events tab and you can choose your handler for events there.